# Django Tastypie Postgres slow server response

Tags: python, django, performance, apache, postgresql

The problem:

- Server responses to calls (measured by opbeat, DHC chrome client) are
  around 500ms to 5000ms. The Postgres queries (in total, per call)
  are about 20x-50x faster than their corresponding response times. Why so slow?!?

The context:

- I'm running a live tastypie API on webfaction (shared instance, 1 gig ram :( ) for our mobile app. Django 1.8, Python 2.7, 0.12.2.dev0 tastypie, PostgreSQL 9.4., CentOS7
- The db has about 40 tables, ~2gigs, 6k users (maybe 1/3rd are 'active'), db is on separate shared webfaction box for dbs.
- While we do have some procedural code in the api, many of the slow calls are simply GETs to a user's resources- largest/slowest being ~50kb of records, ~350 objects in JSON response. The postgres time on this call is ~20-50ms, fastest time on DHC is about 2 seconds on fast dedicated dev server--2gig ram, 2 procs-- and ~4 sec on live, slowest is about 10-16 seconds on both boxes.
- Running on Apache/mod_wsgi, HTTPS, (benchmarks of apache are fast), no gzip. httpd.conf settings seem fine.

In a nutshell:

- 99% of time is spent within tastypie.resources.wrapper - I haven't messed with this code. These calls are simply calls to return resources.
- Database queries are fast
- Webserver seems fast.

Diagnostics:

**Django debug toolbar** (for fastest call of slowest operation on dev dedicated box)

User CPU time   1926.979 msec

System CPU time 27.074 msec

Total CPU time  1954.053 msec

Elapsed time    1980.884 msec

Context switches    71 voluntary, 44 involuntary

**httpd.conf**

```
LoadModule authz_core_module modules/mod_authz_core.so

LoadModule dir_module        modules/mod_dir.so

LoadModule env_module        modules/mod_env.so

LoadModule log_config_module modules/mod_log_config.so

LoadModule mime_module       modules/mod_mime.so

LoadModule rewrite_module    modules/mod_rewrite.so

LoadModule setenvif_module   modules/mod_setenvif.so

LoadModule wsgi_module       modules/mod_wsgi.so

LoadModule unixd_module      modules/mod_unixd.so

...

KeepAlive Off

SetEnvIf X-Forwarded-SSL on HTTPS=1

ServerLimit 1

StartServers 1

MaxRequestWorkers 5

MinSpareThreads 1

MaxSpareThreads 3

ThreadsPerChild 5

...

WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}

WSGIDaemonProcess djangoapp processes=2 threads=8 python-path=...

WSGIProcessGroup djangoapp

WSGIRestrictEmbedded On

WSGILazyInitialization On
```

**Opbeat on live server** (this grab has more/longer db queries for I was testing the removal of selecte_related()/prefetch_related()- they helped the db query times but not the much off the total time):

Wtf, 10 reputation to post images?

[image: opbeat performance breakdown chart/graph posted by a n00b]

And last thoughts:

- Is tastypie just this slow? Surely not. While the better box runs it ~faster, is it realistic to take python 2 seconds to dish out what took the db 20ms?
- Yeah, when I put it on a faster, dedicated dev box, the times come down a bit, but they are still about 10-50x the time it takes to do the SQL call, e.g. they are still  2 seconds as the fastest for a resource GET that took the db < 50ms. So, it doesn't seem to be merely a resources issue, AFAIK.
- I tried to link to an amazon RDS postgres db but its times were about 20x slower (micro/free tier) for the db calls and slower as well for total round trip time.
- Thanks for your help and interest-

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my investigation `Tastypie` is slow, bacause function `django.core.urlresolvers.reverse` is slow.

I resigned from `resource_uri` and patch `Tastypie` in this way:

### django_app/monkey/tastypie.py

```
from __future__ import absolute_import

from django.core.exceptions import ObjectDoesNotExist
from tastypie.bundle import Bundle
from tastypie.exceptions import ApiFieldError


def dehydrate(self, bundle, for_list=True):
    if not bundle.obj or not bundle.obj.pk:
        if not self.null:
            raise ApiFieldError(
                "The model '%r' does not have a primary key and can not be used in a ToMany context." % bundle.obj)

        return []

    the_m2ms = None
    previous_obj = bundle.obj
    attr = self.attribute

    if isinstance(self.attribute, basestring):
        attrs = self.attribute.split('__')
        the_m2ms = bundle.obj

        for attr in attrs:
            previous_obj = the_m2ms
            try:
                the_m2ms = getattr(the_m2ms, attr, None)
            except ObjectDoesNotExist:
                the_m2ms = None

            if not the_m2ms:
                break

    elif callable(self.attribute):
        the_m2ms = self.attribute(bundle)

    if not the_m2ms:
        if not self.null:
            raise ApiFieldError(
                "The model '%r' has an empty attribute '%s' and doesn't allow a null value." % (previous_obj, attr))

        return []

    self.m2m_resources = []
    m2m_dehydrated = []

    # TODO: Also model-specific and leaky. Relies on there being a
    # ``Manager`` there.
    m2ms = the_m2ms.all() if for_list else the_m2ms.get_query_set().all()
    for m2m in m2ms:
        m2m_resource = self.get_related_resource(m2m)
        m2m_bundle = Bundle(obj=m2m, request=bundle.request)
        self.m2m_resources.append(m2m_resource)
        m2m_dehydrated.append(self.dehydrate_related(m2m_bundle, m2m_resource, for_list=for_list))

    return m2m_dehydrated


def _build_reverse_url(self, name, args=None, kwargs=None):
    return kwargs.get('pk')


def get_via_uri(self, uri, request=None):
    bundle = self.build_bundle(request=request)
    return self.obj_get(bundle=bundle, pk=uri)


def build_related_resource(self, value, request=None, related_obj=None, related_name=None):
    """
    Returns a bundle of data built by the related resource, usually via
    ``hydrate`` with the data provided.

    Accepts either a URI, a data dictionary (or dictionary-like structure)
    or an object with a ``pk``.
    """
    self.fk_resource = self.to_class()
    kwargs = {
        'request': request,
        'related_obj': related_obj,
        'related_name': related_name,
    }

    if isinstance(value, Bundle):
        # Already hydrated, probably nested bundles. Just return.
        return value
    elif isinstance(value, (basestring, int)):
        # We got a URI. Load the object and assign it.
        return self.resource_from_uri(self.fk_resource, value, **kwargs)
    elif isinstance(value, Bundle):
        # We got a valid bundle object, the RelatedField had full=True
        return value
    elif hasattr(value, 'items'):
        # We've got a data dictionary.
        # Since this leads to creation, this is the only one of these
        # methods that might care about "parent" data.
        return self.resource_from_data(self.fk_resource, value, **kwargs)
    elif hasattr(value, 'pk'):
        # We've got an object with a primary key.
        return self.resource_from_pk(self.fk_resource, value, **kwargs)
    else:
        raise ApiFieldError("The '%s' field was given data that was not a URI, not a dictionary-alike and does not have a 'pk' attribute: %s." % (self.instance_name, value))
```

### django_app/monkey/**init**.py

```
def patch_tastypie():
    from tastypie.fields import ToManyField, RelatedField
    from tastypie.resources import Resource, ResourceOptions
    from monkey.tastypie import dehydrate, _build_reverse_url, get_via_uri, build_related_resource

    setattr(ToManyField, 'dehydrate', dehydrate)
    setattr(Resource, '_build_reverse_url', _build_reverse_url)
    setattr(Resource, 'get_via_uri', get_via_uri)
    setattr(ResourceOptions, 'include_resource_uri', False)
    setattr(RelatedField, 'build_related_resource', build_related_resource)
```

### django_app/**init**.py

```
from __future__ import absolute_import

from .monkey import patch_tastypie


patch_tastypie()
```

It's not perfect, but speed-up `Tastypie` 10-20%

Comment: Thanks Tomasz- sorry to be dense, but where exactly do these snippets go? Psyched to try this.

Comment: Okay, I added the code but it seems to have made no difference in my response times :( damn!
Thanks for this, though, Tomasz.

Comment: Show resource code. Which Django version? Which Tastypie version? Which Python? I will try to investigate.

Comment: Versions are all at top (Django 1.8, Python 2.7, 0.12.2.dev0 tastypie, PostgreSQL 9.4., CentOS7). I am trying to make sure that you patch is getting run correctly atm...

Comment: I patched `Tastypie 0.9.16`. Maybe You must make some changes?

Comment: Hmm, so I needed to add 'from future import absolute_import' to init.py and rename it to _ init _.py as well as move it around my janky file tree to get it to run/import all parts. After a lot of tweaking, it seems that the patch of getting it not to _build_reverse_url has the most impact on my times, though it takes the (dev server) time from 2.15 seconds down to 1.85 seconds. Unfortunately the url uri is important to our front end, so I can't ditch it. This does partly explain the slowness but it's nowhere near a 10-20x reduction :(

Comment: Now I see typo: 10-20%. Sorry for this mistake.

Comment: I suppose this shall be the answer for now, though the improvement was not what I was hoping for! Thanks for the help, though.